# How to update Ubuntu (and the kernel) without updating Grub's configuration

Tags: 14.04, grub2, updates

there is a way, as in subject, to update Ubuntu, and in particular its kernel, *without* update the `grub`?

In few words, I need to preserve the state and the version of my `grub` and `grub.cfg`, after every updating.

The version is: `Grub 2.02 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is that you can't (that I'm aware of), unless you know the intricacies of how to manually edit the `grub` configuration and list files that it uses for booting, however if your goal is to preserve the current state and version of `grub` and the `grub.cfg` (including the list of options for Grub to boot from) you ultimately can't achieve your update goal.

Updating the kernel means you need `grub` to identify the new kernel when you boot, in that it has to specifically say "Use this kernel instead of that other kernel." during the boot process.

There's no way around that (that I'm aware of), because if you don't update grub, you will never boot to the new kernel.

Comment: It is what I dreaded. I wait tomorrow, and - if I have no other answers - I will approve your.

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni you may want to wait a couple of days, I'm not as familiar with grub, but my understanding is as my answer states.

Comment: Yes, I have readed. :-)

Comment: Ok, more quietly: I trust on you. Your explanation is very clear.